# Android unlock keyguard programmatically

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I have found many SO links related with device unlock. Still could not understand much. I want to create a wifi based device unlock. So, whenever I am connected to the marked Wifi network, the android phone should be kept unlocked, bypassing the default password/pin/pattern setting. When I move out of region, it needs to be applied again.

I tried to use broadcast receiver when Wifi state changes, then remove device lock using disableKeyguard() (ofcourse after checking some conditions). But I can't bring keyguard to default state, using reenableKeyguard() probably due to the fact KeyguardLock value can not be preserved across broadcast requests. Also, newKeyguardLock() is deprecated. It suggests to "Use FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD and/or FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED instead;" Can this flag disable keyguard from a broadcast receiver?

Should I use a service instead? Let me know your suggestions.

Comment: 3rd party apps can't remove the keyguard completely, they can only display itself over it.

Comment: Thanks, but Smart Unlock(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.loadinghome.smartunlock&hl=en) does it. Not sure how do they achieve it.

Comment: Let me reformulate that: The official API can't do that. Besides of the KeyguardLock you already mentioned, but that is legacy code and probably won't work on newer versions...